# Jsoup get the status code

Tags: java, jsoup

I need to check the status code of a request with Jsoup and if 200 go to parse html.

If I use this:

```
dom = jSoupClass.connect( "http://www.google.it" )
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
    .execute();

status = dom.statusCode();
```

I will get the response status code, but how can I then parse the html?

Comment: The method `connect()` is static, so you should do a static call like `Jsoup.connect("...")`.

Comment: Hey could you tell me what does the userAgent does in your code ? I'm not sure I get it.

Comment: Simply add user-agent header to the request. I add this to avoid been blocked from sites that does not accept automated request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `parse()` on the response like `Document doc = dom.parse()` should do.